# copy object location to another scene? BGE

Tags: game-engine, scene

I have a dummy object parented to a vertice of the health bar of my main character on the first scene the health bar works accurately and the dummy fallows the vertice parenting, I have an object on the other overlay scene render correctly, but I need to to fallow the location of the dummy on the first scene. How may I get this to work when I'm playing? thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

- You want interaction between two scenes? Pointless. Make one scene.
- You want to "augment" the main scene with your overlay and need to place things on top of each other? Do it in screen space, don't do it XYZ or what ever. Simply measure where your desired location is visible on your monitor. Make a global storage to place your result in. Then in the other scene read from there, to place your "augmentation" on the spot.

**EDIT:**

First: It's quite hard to understand you. My apologies.
But: Have you ever played multiplayer games before? That has to work somehow, doesn't it? Im sure, you need not be afraid of Blender limiting anything across your scenes...

*In fact however, talking about limitations, Blenders game engine is really a bad choice. I tested it for myself, you don't even have delta times for your animations. The game engine is simply not an objective for the developers.*

With that, I want to draw your attention to render layers. Search them through google, maybe they are just what you wanted.

In relation to your original question, I think you have some issue understanding the situation.

Let me clarify:

- Your Scenes are ***seperate***. And they are meant to be!

"cloning" anything in a scene into another scene ***is*** pointless, since it conflicts with the purpose of scenes.

But, of course you can. In this case you need at least the camera vector and/or the desired objects vector to be cloned. Which reveals the problem: Different dimensions.
You can have a Camera over a map moving according to the players location in the main scene. You always must do a *translation*, even if sizes and locations stay the same.

I hope this helps.

Comment: well I want one object to match another (animated) object on a different scene, that's why... also your "pointless" comment isn't helpful, if what I ask is a blender limitation then say so. But from my view creating my game i can dispense with this detail but it would be nice if I had this sort of thing as I want it.

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/t/bge-mini-map-for-2-72/627633

Answer (score 0):

I also have issues with camera LOD for my openworld game.
I was successfully link object to scene with the camera so the LOD works properly, however.....
I just make a simple fly movement from camera parent using logic, the problem was the physics that occurs to each master parent were not syncronized even just a small movement like moving on the slopes.
I realize I was using the wrong way with Physics applied onto my camera parents, because each of the scene has the same logic and hierarchy, from character parrent until camera.

But there is a complete game template that works properly called "Bueraki" its still uncovered to me how to make such camera with a proper Link from Main scene into LOD scene, I just found that the camera in LOD were Link from master file library. using Phyton code like "getcurrentscene" code, and I still figure it how to make this works.